# Why didn't the army use its influence to save Gen. Parvez Musharraf from numerous cases?

Tags: military, pakistan

It is generally believed that the Pakistan army has a great influence on Pakistan's politics and judiciary.

If that is the truth, then why couldn't Gen. Pervez Musharraf avoid a myriad of cases against him for which he is living in Dubai in exile?

Comment: I would say it may happen in future, for example Nawaz Sharif was also in exile but under the current circumstances it seems he may return

Comment: @RamanujanXXV, Nawaz Sharif was not an army chief.

Comment: I know that very well,I was just giving an example of how things can change in future depending on who is in power

Comment: @RamanujanXXV, Bringing up NS was uncalled for as he is not part of the military fraternity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, Musharraf had lost influence and support within the armed forces. The armed forces are not uniform and even they have different factions. As long as Musharraf commanded their loyalty he could be kept in power. Once it was lost he was out. Kiyani (who was on Time's list of most powerful people during his time as chief of the army in Pakistan) was appointed by Musharraf. However, Kiyani refused to safeguard Musharraf against political actions:

> Musharraf's handpicked successor as army chief, Gen. Ashfaq Kiyani, is
> unlikely to come to the rescue of his old boss, analysts said. Kiyani
> last week issued an order that no military officers can meet with the
> president without his approval and indicated that he would recall the
> many military officers placed in civilian jobs under Musharraf.

In Pakistan, once you lose the support of the military you can no longer be in power, [which is what happened to Imran Khan just a few weeks ago](https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna22816391):

> "The army would be very happy to get rid of him," said one political
> analyst, Talat Masood, a retired Pakistani general.

Comment: Musharraf didn't handpick Kyani. Kyani was the choice of Asif Ali Zardari with advice from the USA.  Proof: In the case of the MemoGate scandal, Kyani kept silent.

Comment: Imran Khan was not an army person. Also, he was defeated by the advice, pressure, and money of the USA.

Comment: @user366312 Maybe you buy that maybe you don't it's Imran's own party line regarding his removal. But it is well established that fallout with the military led to his removal. Al Jazeera etc.

Comment: *But it is well established that fallout with the military-led to his removal. Al Jazeera etc.* --- give me at least one source.

Comment: *it's Imran's own party line regarding his removal* --- what does it even mean?

Comment: @user366312 so in politics there are no facts. Each side has different stories. The story a party tells to give it's side is the party line. For eg. on Imran Khan's removal - PPP and ML(N)'s party line is that Imran was removed cos he was incompetent whereas PTI's Party Line is that they were removed cos of Foreign influence. It is up to you which one you believe. Regardless of that, the fact remains that the military stopped supporting khan and that lead to his ouster

Comment: Given the fact that Imran has zero track record of corruption, money laundering, embezzlement, or Panama papers, ... obviously, I trust IK.

Comment: @user366312 Stack Politics is not a political opinion website. Your stance is valid but it is irrelevant whether you believe him or not. We are only here to discuss structural designs that led to Musharraf not being able to retake his position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136688/discussion-between-ash-rivers-and-user366312).

Answer (score -1):

The answer comes from the quote taken from a [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Leopard) written several decades ago.

> If we want that nothing changes, everything must change.

It happens often when politics is too much personalised and focused on few people hailed as great leaders. When people start protesting too much against the status quo the leader steps aside in a manner that is as spectacular as possible and carries with them all the blame, thus the surrounding power structure is left unchanged.